# Can't I run multiple javascript functions with setInterval on a page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

**Update**

*Turns out, coding while tired is not optimal. As pointed out in the comments, I was missing the definition of `oneHour` in `countdownAutoLogout()`... It must have been accidentally deleted in the copy & paste-process... Sorry for the inconvenience! I'll show myself out.*

---

I have two almost identical countdown functions located in `site.js`. One is working, the other not so much.

I used to have only `countdownAutoLogout()`, and it was working as expected. Upon adding `countdownMeeting(durationSeconds)`, `countdownAutoLogout()` is only initiated, but doesn't count down, as I have illustrated with the `alert()`s in the code.

`countdownAutoLogout()` is called in the `<body>`-tag in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<body onload="javascript: countdownAutoLogout();">
```

`countdownMeeting(durationSeconds)` is called in the scripts section in the view:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Model.RemainingSeconds is a model property of type double.
            countdownMeeting(@Model.RemainingSeconds);
        })
    </script>
}
```

The functions:

```
// Padding with leading zero:
function pad(str, max, padder) {
    padder = typeof padder === "undefined"
        ? "0"
        : padder;
    return str.toString().length < max
        ? pad(padder.toString() + str, max, padder)
        : str;
}

function countdownAutoLogout() {

    alert("This alert pops up.");

    var oneMinute = 60000;
    var twoHours = oneMinute * 121;
    var countDownDate = Date.now() + twoHours;

    var x = setInterval(function () {
        var now = Date.now();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (oneHour * 24)) / oneHour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % oneHour) / oneMinute);

        alert("This alert doesn't pop up.");

        document.getElementById("SessionCookieExpirationCountdown").innerHTML =
            pad(hours, 2) + ":" + pad(minutes, 2);

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            location.href = "/Home/Timeout";
        }
    }, 5000);
}

// This function is working smoothly:
function countdownMeeting(durationSeconds) {
    var oneMinute = 60000;
    var oneHour = oneMinute * 60;
    var duration = oneMinute * durationSeconds / 60;
    var countDownDate = Date.now() + duration;

    var x = setInterval(function () {
        var now = Date.now();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (oneHour * 24)) / oneHour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % oneHour) / oneMinute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % oneMinute) / 1000);

        document.getElementById("MeetingDurationCountdown").innerHTML =
            pad(hours, 2) + ":" + pad(minutes, 2) + ":" + pad(seconds, 2);

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("MeetingDurationCountdown").innerHTML = "Overtime!";
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Aren't you seeing the error in the console? `oneHour` is not defined in `countdownAutoLogout()`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the second function.

Comment: umm in your pad function undefined should not be in quotes `undefined !== "undefined"`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! I'm not used to debugging javascript, so I rarely check the console. I'm just buried in Visual Studio, and it does not have javascript debugging capabilities.